Issues with the on_bad_lines parameter in read_csv
In pandas, how to get the value when using pandas.read_csv() with the parameter on_bad_lines='warn'? Using standard output streams cannot obtain it.
Assigning the output information to a variable.
I am currently unable to retrieve the information prompted by on_bad_lines='warn'.
